# Package doclicense gives error with hyperxmp; PDF is produced

Tags: hyperxmp

Compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={4.0},
    lang={spanish}
]{doclicense}

\usepackage{lipsum,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1-3]
    
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get the follwing error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hyxmp@dc@lang
```

However, even with the error, a PDF is produced. How does one get rid of the error? This started happening after my last TeXLive upgrade; current version is 2020.20200925-1 (running on Debian Testing); `doclicense` is version 2.2.1.dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `doclicence` package says that it requires `hyperxmp`. However, your code would not run for me unless I explicitly loaded `hyperxmp` under v2.2.0 of `doclicense`. When I updated to v2.2.1 of doclicense the issue went away. (I have v5.4 of `hyperxmp`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={4.0},
    lang={spanish}
]{doclicense}

\usepackage{lipsum,siunitx,hyperxmp} % <--- load hyperxmp with v2.2.0 of doclicense

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1-3]
    
\end{document}
```

By loading `hyperxmp` explicitly, I got the output shown below with v2.2.0 of `doclicense`:
[image]

Comment: Right! I suppose the version I have of `doclicense` is still "in development", because it says it is v.2.2.1.dev. This works; what I don't understand is why now, I had been working with files using `doclicense` before without this error. Thanks!